# Смысл выражения "точить лясы"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Объясните, пожалуйста, значение выражения "точить лясы".

Comment: См. http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/2591/%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC_%D0%9B%D0%AF%D0%A1%D0%AB

Answer (score 1):

Значение-то понятно: заниматься пустой болтовней. Вот происхождение этого фразеологизма – другое дело.

Answer (score 0):

Значение - да: балагурить, пустословить, сплетничать, трепаться о пустяках;  бесцельно, праздно проводить время, обычно в ущерб делу.

Но у фразеологизма "точить лясы" есть и другая (полная) форма: "точить балясы" и даже  "разводить балясы"...

***Балясы — выдумки, ерунда, чушь.***

Этимология (предположительная):

> Лясы (балясы) — это точеные фигурные столбики перил у крылечка;
>   изготовить такую красоту мог только настоящий мастер. Наверное,
>   сначала «точить балясы» означало вести изящную, причудливую,
>   витиеватую (как балясы) беседу. А умельцев вести такую беседу к нашему
>   времени становилось меньше и меньше. Вот и стало это выражение
>   обозначать пустую болтовню.
>
> ---

У Даля:

> Балясы мн. более употреб. чем балясины: *лясы, белентрясы, балы,
>   шутки, веселые россказни. Точить балясы, балясить, балясничать,
>   шутить, галить, смеяться, забавно беседовать. Балясничанье ср.
>   действие по глаг. Балясник м. токарь, промышляющий точением балясин;
>   промысел (ниж.-сем.) этот упадает со времени введения по Волге
>   пароходства; балясы шли на коноводки. || Лес, большей частью осиновый,
>   приготовленный для точки баляс. || *Шутник, рассказчик, остряк,
>   проказник, лясник, балагур, балызник; балясница, шутница, потешница.

Вот любопытный, но, возможно, излишне подробный для ответа [**культурологический комментарий**](http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/2588/%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC_%D0%91%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%AF%D0%A1%D0%AB), который уводит от витиевато точёных столбиков-перилец-балясин:

> фразеол. "образован на основе рус. баля/сы "россказни", укр. баля/с
>   "шум", восходящих непосредственно к общеславянскому корню *bal-
>   "рассказывать". Слова ба/лы и ля/сы широко известны в говорах и в
>   свободном употреблении в значении "пустые разговоры, болтовня". Как и
>   корень *bal-, корень *las- в русских говорах характеризуется
>   продуктивностью: ля/сить и ля/сничать "рассказывать о былом и
>   небылицах", "балагурить", "льстить", "говорить пустяки" зафиксированы
>   на широком ареале. Все эти глаголы тесно связаны с экспрессивным
>   праславянским корнем *luzg-/lyzg-/lusk-/lysk-, имеющим широкий набор
>   значений. В говорах слова ба/лы, баля/сы и ля/сы сочетаются со многими
>   глаголами, особенно - связанными с процессом говорения (гуторить,
>   говорить, правиць и др.), либо с процессом превращения в нечто текучее
>   (рус. растворить, разводить), либо с производственными процессами
>   (вязать, собирать, строить, городить). **Глагол точить (точать) в
>   говорах активно сочетается с существительными, имеющими значение
>   "болтовня"**: донск. точа/ть бала/нды, бала/чку тача/ть; точа/ть
>   (точи/ть) ба/лы (ба/лки), брихни/ тача/ть, точа/ть (точи/ть) ерунду/,
>   арх. точи/ть ба/лы, белом. точи/ть ба/злы, ставр. балендро/сы точа/ть,
>   томск., ср.-обск., ирк. ля/салки точи/ть, яросл. ля/сы-баля/сы
>   точи/ть, пск. точи/ть ля/скалы, точи/ть ре/чи; новг. ста/вры точи/ть;
>   бел. тачы/ць ба/снi, укр. точи/ти баля/ндраси, бре/хни точи/ти,
>   тереве/нi точи/ти и т. п. Все эти выражения значат "болтать",
>   "пустословить". **Всё сказанное позволяет видеть в глаголе точить не
>   привычную сейчас семантику "заострять, вытачивать из металла или
>   дерева", а более древнее значение "источать какую-л. жидкость", а
>   переносно - "источать слова, говорить".** Древность конкретного значения
>   подтверждается широкими индоевропейскими параллелями (ср. книжн.
>   точить слёзы "плакать", связь корней в словах река и речь и т. п.).
>   Переход значений от "источать жидкость" к "говорить" - древнейшая
>   метафора, засвидетельствованная многими языками. ср. рус. речь его
>   струилась, лилась, текла, речь его плавно журчала, расточать
>   [напрасно] речи. Выражение точить лясы (балясы), следовательно,
>   первоначально значило "источать звуки, изливать речи". Оборот возник,
>   видимо, гораздо раньше XVIII в. Происхождение его - общеславянское,
>   вероятно, древнерусское". (Бирих А.К., Мокиенко В.М., Степанова Л.И.
>   Словарь русской фразеологии. Историко-этимологический справочник.
>   СПб., 1998. С. 356-359.) Другая версия происхождения фразеол. состоит
>   в том, что выражение первоначально использовалось в профессиональной
>   речи в значении "вытачивать узорные фигурные столбики перил" (слова
>   балясы и лясы "резные украшения некоторых частей здания, перил"
>   происходят от итал. balaustro "столбик, точёные перильца" и попали в
>   русский язык через польский - ср. польск. balas, balasy). Значение
>   "болтать, пустословить" сложилось метафорическим путём (вытачивая
>   балясы, развлекались разговорами) не позднее XVIII в. Однако эта
>   версия, высказанная многими лингвистами, в т. ч. и в кн. Н.М.
>   Шанского, В.И. Зимина и А.В. Филиппова "Опыт этимологического словаря
>   русской фразеологии" (М., 1987. С. 145), менее убедительна, т. к.
>   связь фразеол. с балясы, балясина "резной или точёный столбик", укр.
>   баляси "перила" вторична, она вызвана народно-этимологическими
>   ассоциациями. Таким образом, культурный смысл фразеол. следует
>   охарактеризовать с опорой на первую этимологию. Образ фразеол.
>   воспринимается на фоне традиционно отрицательного отношения к
>   болтливости, отчего фразеол. в целом играет роль стереотипного
>   представления о болтовне, пустословии.

Answer (score 0):

Это аналогично выражению "бить баклуши" - т.е заниматься праздной работой. "Баклуша" - заготовка для ложки, как и "балясина" - заготовка для стойки перил.

Comment: Бить баклуши может не каждый, это — как лес валить, чтоб потом избу срубить на года. О какой праздности речь... И балясина — не заготовка, а точёная на токарном станке стойка, тело вращения.